# How to ignore empty rows in CSV when reading

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

Trying to read a CSV file that has empty rows (usually at the end) using `CsvHelper.GetRecords<T>()`.

Without the empty rows this works a treat. However if the CSV file has an empty row (defined as , , , , , ) then it throws a `TypeConverterException`

```
Text: ''
MemberType: IntelligentEditing.PerfectIt.Core.DataTypes.Styles.StyleRuleType
TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.EnumConverter'
```

I have gone through the documentation (https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/Configuration/) and have tried setting up the configuration object to `IgnoreBlankLines = true` however this has not worked.

Simplified for an example:

```cs
public enum ItemTypeEnum
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Accounts = 1,
    HR = 2,
}


public class CsvItemDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ItemTypeEnum ItemType { get; set; }
}

.
.
.
var configuration = new Configuration()
{
    HasHeaderRecord = true,
    HeaderValidated = null,
    MissingFieldFound = null,
    IgnoreBlankLines = true,

};
var csv = new CsvReader(textReader, configuration);
var rows = csv.GetRecords<CsvItemDto>();


if (rows != null)
{
    var items = rows.ToList();
    //Throws exception here
}
```

The CSV would usually contain something like this:

```
Id,Value,ItemType
1,This,Unknown
2,That,Accounts
3,Other,HR
,,
,,
```

I expected the `IgnoreBlankLines` to ignore the blank rows in the CSV but it is not. Any ideas?

Comment: These lines with only a dot will be interpreted as being the first column, which is numeric input. No matter how you twist that, for a bare integer column, that _is_ illegal input. If these were only put there as vertical '...' ellipsis, please leave them out of the example.

Comment: @Nyerguds apologies I should have made it clear that the dots were other rows that I haven't been bothered to type. Ill remove them for clarity.Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to implement ShouldSkipRecord on Configuration to choose skip or not

```cs
var configuration = new Configuration () {
                HasHeaderRecord = true,
                HeaderValidated = null,
                MissingFieldFound = null,
                IgnoreBlankLines = true,
                ShouldSkipRecord = (records) =>
                {
                    // Implement logic here
                    return false;
                }
            };
```

Comment: I did consider that I just assumed that this problem is straightforward configuration boolean setting. If no other answers appear I will probably go with this answer

Answer (score 14):

In addition to @David Specht's answer. The newer version has updated delegate `ShouldSkipRecord`. I am using version 28.0.1, the code below works for me.

```cs
ShouldSkipRecord = args => args.Row.Parser.Record.All(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)
```

Answer (score 12):

@phat.huynh has the right idea. Just tell it to skip any record where all the fields are empty strings.

```cs
var configuration = new Configuration()
{
    HasHeaderRecord = true,
    HeaderValidated = null,
    MissingFieldFound = null,
    ShouldSkipRecord = record => record.All(field => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field))
};
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field)` which will cover empty as well as other invisible characters that might be in incoming CSV stream

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way, in [`CsvHelper 23.0.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/23.0.0), is managing the reader exceptions

```
var conf = new CsvConfiguration(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
conf.ReadingExceptionOccurred = (exc) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
    return false;
};
```

One can log it, throw it, bypass it returning false and even discriminate behaviors having a look at the exception source.