# Ignore Empty Row CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Is there any way to ignore a row when using CSVHelper when the row contains no values?

ie: a row like...

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I've tried

```
    config.IgnoreBlankLines = true ;
    config.MissingFieldFound = null ; 
    config.UseNewObjectForNullReferenceMembers = false;
```

none of which are doing what I'm after.

To get around this, I'm reading the whole file first and re-writing the CSV without the lines containing missing data.

Comment: CSVHelper provides the ShouldSkipRecord callback that you can use to determine whether a row should be skipped during reading

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73315891/3744182) by Bowen to [How to ignore empty rows in CSV when reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73315891/3744182) for an example of how to use [`ShouldSkipRecord`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/7b3ed4d45af8385e732a42eb161b0d129736edb3/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L151C36-L151C53) to skip rows with all empty cells.  See also [`ShouldSkipRecordTests.SkipEmptyRowTest()`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/tests/CsvHelper.Tests/Reading/ShouldSkipRecordTests.cs#L41) from the source.

Comment: Thanks, the entry 
   ShouldSkipRecord = args => args.Row.Parser.Record.All(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)
Fixed my problem.  It's only an issue when the class has a not nullable type and the CSV field is essentially null.   The standard config runs fine when all fields are strings.